# MQTT over serial

Tags: serial, raspberrypi, home-automation, mqtt

I'm planning to build a 32 relay IOT node next to my Raspberry Pi. The relays will be controlled by an Arduino Mega 2560. The Pi will run Home Assistant and Mosquitto so I would prefer to communicate with the arduino using MQTT.
The Arduino and the Pi will be next to each other, the simplest connection would be over serial.
I have found a library: https://github.com/vortex314/serial2mqtt it looks not easy to set up. Do you have any other ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need MQTT over serial. You can just send the number of the relay that should be turned on over serial?

Comment: That library is designed for the ESP32 which has substantially more power than the Mega2560.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution!
Using mysensors (mysensors.org) I can use the Arduino Mega as a node and a serial gateway. So Home Assistant can control it directly.

Answer (score 5):

As the author of the serial2mqtt gateway. Maybe it's time to have a new look. I've included the binaries for different platforms in the build : https://github.com/vortex314/serial2mqtt/tree/master/build
So to get started : unzip the binary and update the serial2mqtt.json config.
Should be piece of cake. Let me know otherwise via github.

Comment: Thank you @Lieven
It's a very nice project. Even the documentation is very useful. I already have my system set up but I will keep in mind serial2mqtt. I will definitely try it out.